# Cant decode specific transaction input from rollups appendSequencerBatch method

Tags: rollups, method

I can easly decode some standard methods and their inputs to get method name and all the parametars but this one specific I cant and all I get is

```
{ method: 'appendSequencerBatch', types: [], inputs: [], names: [] }
```

Would like to get some help on how to decode this input data and why is it not possible to decode it "regulary"?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x287f436dec03efa803bfff387cadb3b97f8eb05ad59f663395450599b11c02ab

Comment: What do you mean by "regularly"? From the [signature database](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=d0f89344) it appears the function is `appendSequencerBatch()`. So it is likely it isn't using the standard ABI to encode the parameters.

Comment: I tried tools like https://cleanunicorn.github.io/santoku/ or just plain truffle+JS code, where I get the above with not params, but when It with any other trx I get all.
This is trx from Rollups btw, using calldata.

Comment: I've looked around and it seems related to Optimism mechanisms for batching transaction, see https://research.paradigm.xyz/optimism.